# corrupted usb stuck on read only

Tags: usb, repair, write-protect

I had a perfectly fine usb working normal 32GB. Now i reformat it with windoes to fat32. took it to mac to load image file using disk utility. which did not work. now the usb is set to read only. i cannot find any way to fix this. tried the usual registry edit but does not work. On mac it does not let me repair as it is greyed out. on windows i cannot do anything. it keeps saying it is write protected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Answer (score 2):

***My suggestion would be*** to find and download some kind of USB Formatting Program, install it, and use that to try and re-format the drive.  Here is a link to one that I found real quick that may work for you, but if it doesn't, you could just Google "USB Formating Program's" and you should find a whole bunch to choose from... Just be careful when downloading ANYTHING!! There's A LOT of false download button's that re-direct you to other site's or try and download other, more malicious program's than you mean to download... Just look really carefully at the buttons before you click them and you should be fine.

http://download.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html

***P.S.***If you need more help with that program, or finding another one, feel free to ask, I'd be happy to help...

Answer (score 0):

I wound try to re-format the usb: delete the partition and create a clean one.

Comment: I cannot reformat. it is read only. i cannot delete partition. i cannot do anything on it.